# Order by number with letter and blank value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I try to select (with php) a value with a specific order, I have this value (that's just an example):

```
ID * NAME    * NUMBER
1  * LUIS    * 1
2  * ARNOLD  * 2
3  * Toby    *      //blank
4  * Thomas  * 3
5  * LOL     * 2A
```

How can i have this result :

```
ID * NAME    * NUMBER
3  * Toby    *       //blank
1  * LUIS    * 1
2  * ARNOLD  * 2   
5  * LOL     * 2A
4  * Thomas  * 3
```

I tried with much query but nothing always get 'wrong' result.

For example I tried the answer of another question:

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3f965/1)

```
select * from table
order by if(field = '' or field is null,1,0),field
```

But result was 'wrong', mean it's not order like my example.

Comment: Are you selecting using SQL? Show us the SQL you wrote.

Comment: What does 'wrong' result mean?

Comment: Did you try "ORDER BY NUMBER" ?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: try as `ORDER BY NUMBER != '' DESC, NUMBER  ASC`

Comment: We would rather solutions are added only as answers, rather than also being added into the question. I've rolled this back for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the answer:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(number) asc, number asc
```

Now the order is ok.